# fetching logs from API but not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I have been trying to fetch data from an API, but the logs seem to show the responseJSON however, it is not appearing on my front end.

This is my code for fetching api:

```
componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('http://atiiuserauth.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/home')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState(
          {
            isLoading: false,
            data: responseJson,
          },
          console.log(responseJson)
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

This is my reandermethod()

```
 render() {
    const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');
    const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
    const like = this.state.liked ? 'red' : 'white';

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>

        <FlatList
        datasource={this.state.data}

        renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style = {{alignContent: 'stretch'}}>
        <Video 
          source={{ uri: item.urlVid }}
          resizeMode = "cover"
          style={{width: "100%", height: 800}}
        />
         <View
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                alignItems: 'flex-end',
                top: '50%',
                right: 10,
              }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.handleClick}
                style={{
                  alignItems: 'center',

                  borderRadius: 60,
                  padding: 10,
                }}>
                <Icon
                  name="heart"
                  size={30}
                  color={this.state.buttonColor}
                  onPress={this.onButtonPress}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>


              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  alignItems: 'center',

                  borderRadius: 60,
                  padding: 10,
                }}>
                <Icon name="share" size={30} color="white" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={{ right: 5, color: 'white' }} />
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  alignItems: 'center',

                  borderRadius: 60,
                  padding: 10,
                }}>
                <Icon name="whatsapp" size={30} color="white" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={{ right: 5, color: 'white' }} />
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  alignItems: 'center',

                  borderRadius: 60,
                  padding: 10,
                }}>
                <Icon name="download" size={30} color="white" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={{ right: 5, color: 'white' }} />
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                flexDirection: 'column',

                top: '90%',
                left: 10,
              }}>
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20, color: 'white' }}>
                  {item.title} - {item.price}
                </Text>



              </View>

            </View>

        </View>


        )}
        ListHeaderComponent={this.header}
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
        keyExtractor={ item => item.id}
      />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The logs are:

```
 LOG  {"product": [{"__v": 0, "_id": "5e30067e667d8473f8e79726", "color": "sasasa", "colors": [Array], "description": "sassa", "nameImg": "apex-legends-logo-1580205687689.jpg", "nameVid": "videoplayback-1580205687690.mp4", "sellerID": "sasa", "sellerName": "sasa", "size": "sasa", "sizes": [Array], "title": "wqw", "typeImg": "image/jpeg", "typeVid": "video/mp4", "uploadedOn": "2020-01-28T10:01:34.987Z", "urlImg": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/apex-legends-logo-1580205687689.jpg", "urlVid": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videoplayback-1580205687690.mp4"}, {"__v": 0, "_id": "5e301696f75182463c6874ed", "color": "Space Grey", "colors": [Array], "description": "apple", "nameImg": "61jgfLBydjL._SL1024_-1580209807807.jpg", "nameVid": "videoplayback (1)-1580209807809.mp4", "price": 99900, "sellerID": "13755902031", "sellerName": "Appario", "size": "5.8-inch", "sizes": [Array], "title": "Apple iPhone 11 Pro", "typeImg": "image/jpeg", "typeVid": "video/mp4", "uploadedOn": "2020-01-28T11:10:14.244Z", "urlImg": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/61jgfLBydjL._SL1024_-1580209807807.jpg", "urlVid": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videoplayback+%281%29-1580209807809.mp4"}, {"__v": 0, "_id": "5e30171df75182463c6874ee", "color": "Haze Blue", "colors": [Array], "description": "oneplus", "nameImg": "61FRLa8IFTL._SL1500_-1580209943294.jpg", "nameVid": "videoplayback-1580209943295.mp4", "price": 53999, "sellerID": "13755902031", "sellerName": "OnePlus", "size": "6.67 inch", "sizes": [Array], "title": "OnePlus 7T Pro", "typeImg": "image/jpeg", "typeVid": "video/mp4", "uploadedOn": "2020-01-28T11:12:29.918Z", "urlImg": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/61FRLa8IFTL._SL1500_-1580209943294.jpg", "urlVid": "https://atiiproductmediafiles.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videoplayback-1580209943295.mp4"}], "user": {"__v": 0, "_id": "5e300846241a3b1c89d654c4", "address": [], "changes": [], "checkout": [], "like": [], "mobile": 8697779335, "registeredOn": "2020-01-28T10:09:10.569Z"}}
```

Please help, and point me out my error, please and do tell me if you require any other details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this.state.data.product` in the FlatList, because products are in the product field in the json response.

Also you need to set data to the `data`  property in [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.47/flatlist) instead of datasource.

So the following line:

```js
datasource={this.state.data}
```

must be like this:

```js
data={this.state.data.product}
```